# Wordpress site title order

Tags: php, wordpress

Could anyone tell me how to get my site title to show as:  blog post | title  instead of; title | blog post.

theme code is as follows;

```
<title>
<?php 
 if ( defined('WPSEO_VERSION') ) 
   { 
    wp_title(''); 
   } 
 else 
   { 
 if(is_home() OR is_404() OR is_search() ) 
   { 
    echo bloginfo("name"); 
    echo " | "; echo bloginfo("description"); 
   } 
 else 
   { 
    echo bloginfo("name"); 
    echo " | "; 
    echo get_the_title();  
   } 
  } ?>
</title>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<title><?php if ( defined('WPSEO_VERSION') ) { wp_title(''); } else { if(is_home() OR is_404() OR is_search() ) { echo bloginfo("name"); echo " | "; echo bloginfo("description"); } else { echo get_the_title(); echo " | "; echo bloginfo("name");  } } ?></title>
```

Comment: @JackPoint Hey, what are you talking about. Mark? It's not good for your reputation to ask mark.

Comment: It would be polite for OP to mark this as correct if it works, surely that's what this site is about, @ArshadHussain